# Multiple SQL query in NodeJS

Tags: javascript, mysql, sql, node.js

I have to perform nested queries to return values from the database for a chart. I have to do a total of 12 queries, in which each query adds up the number of customers in each month of the year.
If I use this mode, I get the right result, but written in a horrible way because I do so many lines of code:

```js
sql = "SELECT SUM(customer) as January FROM visit WHERE date >= '2020-01-01 00:00:00' AND date <= '2020-01-31 23:59:59' AND id='4' ";
db.query(sql, function(error, result, result_fields) {
  if (error) {
      res.render('loginform.ejs', { message: err_message, level: "error" } );
      winston.error(error);
  } else {
      //SAVE DATA
      sql = "SELECT SUM(customer) as february FROM visit WHERE date >= '2020-02-01 00:00:00' AND date <= '2020-02-28 23:59:59' AND id='4'";
       //FEBRUARY
       db.query(sql, function(error, result, result_fields) {
         if (error) {
           res.render(...);
           winston.error(error);
         } else {
           req.session.february_customers = ((result[0].february == null)) ? 0 : result[0].February;
...
//This is followed by another 10 queries for the other 10 months of the year.
```

As you can see there are many lines of code !!
Is there any way to optimize? For example using a for loop?

Answer (score 1):

You should to use single query that returns yearly data grouped by month:

```
SELECT
    DATE_FORMAT(date, '%M') AS Month, 
    SUM(customer) as Visits
FROM visit 
WHERE 
    date BETWEEN '2020-01-01 00:00:00' AND '2020-12-31 23:59:59' 
    AND id=4
GROUP BY MONTH(date);
```

Comment: this query into the sql variable?